# iphone: Text around an image

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uitextview, word-wrap

Is it possible to have text go around an image ? like in the picture?
[alt text http://andyj.be/image.png](http://andyj.be/image.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to go with UIWebView as well. You can probably make a guess as to what they're doing by scrolling the page up and down. In my experience, a UIWebView scrolls more sluggishly compared to a UIScrollView, and comes to a stop more quickly.

If you really have your heart set on using a UIScrollView to make this effect, you can use this method:

```
CGSize size = [textView.text sizeWithFont:textView.font
constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(frame.size.width, 9999)
lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

Get your text and put it in a loop. With each iteration of the loop, chop a word off the end. Compare the `size` from the method above to the frame size you want and if it's taller, go through the loop again. When the `size.height` is smaller than what you want, you know how much text to add into the top text view (to the right of the image). Add the rest of the text into the text view under the image, using the above method to size it's frame.

Comment: i actually want to remake an info page like in the appstore if you see info about an application, is the appstore info view made with html in a webview?

Comment: No, the app store isn't using a web view. I've made a view like the app store though. I placed my labels and text views in IB with outlets, then used the method above to size them for variable length text. I kept a running total of the y position and sized my scroll view with that. I didn't do any text wrapping.

Answer (score 2):

I'd be willing to bet that the view in your screenshot is a UIWebView. If you're willing to use UIWebView, then sure you can! Otherwise, I'm not aware of any built-in control that'll allow this to be done easily.